# Moto G (2nd gen) does not support OTG after Lollipop update

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, usb-on-the-go, motorola-moto-g2

I am experiencing problems in transferring video files from SD card to OTG or OTG to SD card.
Its says root directory not found. This started happening after I updated my phone software from KitKat to Lollipop.
Please help.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Formatting the drive with FAT32 solved the problem for me (it was NTFS before).